# Plotbands Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I made the follow polar chart:

[Polar Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/dtq1mfkf/)

My problem is that the plotbands are not even because the distance is not even. I tried fixing it by using 'breaks' in the y-axis.

```
breaks: [{
                from: 10,
                to: 100,
                breakSize: 1
            },{
                from: 4,
                to: 10,
                breakSize: 1
            },{
                from: 1,
                to: 3,
                breakSize: 1
            } ],
```

That made it a little better, but it's stil not want I want. Is there a way to make the size of the plotbands even?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you have uneven ranges for plotBands? For example: from 1 to 3 and from 10 to 100. PlotBands are not even because 2 !== 90 (compare ranges). You can play around more with that breaks to get proper result: http://jsfiddle.net/dtq1mfkf/2/ or just modify plotBands: http://jsfiddle.net/dtq1mfkf/2/ (with proper shape for the area inside the circles).

Comment: I don't understand how breaking the axis to make the bands the same size makes any sense at all...? if the bands need to be the same size, they need to be set to cover the same range. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: I agree. Anyway, here is proper jsfiddle for the modified plotBands: http://jsfiddle.net/dtq1mfkf/3/

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't make allot of sense. It's because its a diagram for the SQALE methode (to measure technical debt of a system) and that method uses that rating grid. The reason I didn't make the plotbands even, is because you couldn't see that the rating "5" falls in the orange zone. And without using breaks, the diagram is 90% red. I just wanted to make the readability better. For the client it is only important to see the value and its color rating. (and not how big or small each rating area is, and thats why I used breaks). But thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use breaks, then the problem will be with points which will fall inside that break, for example, break 10-90, and you will get value 56. Point with 56 value will not be rendered.. See: http://jsfiddle.net/dtq1mfkf/4/

Comment: For the record - though I know many people display this information this way, it is, like almost all polar/radar charts, a terrible way to display it that would be much better displayed as a bar chart. FWIW. That said, either way, rather than breaking the axis, I would assign the plotted value a simple indexed score to fall within whichever band it should, and provide the actual score as extra data to display as a data label and/or tooltip (ie, 5 zones, so make the axis from 1-5 or 0-4, and plot the point accordingly)